# R: curl_fetch_memory returns backslash before each double quotation mark in JSON

Tags: json, r, character-encoding

I am using R to obtain a JSON file with data from a traffic API using curl_fetch_memory function.  The retrieval works, but in the returned JSON file, I am receiving a backslash before every double quotation mark.  Below is the code used to obtain the JSON file:

```
data_temp <- new_handle() %>%
  handle_setheaders("Content-Type" = "application/json", "Authorization" = "apikey blahblahblahblahblah", "User-Agent" = "runscope/0.1") %>%
  curl_fetch_memory(url = "https://api.dataAPIURL") %$% content %>% rawToChar
```

This returns:

```
"{\"type\":\"FeatureCollection\",\"rights\":{\"... <truncated>
```

The / before any " pattern is consistent throughout the entire returned JSON.  I get the feeling this has something to do with the encoding from 'rawToChar' but I cannot seem to narrow it down.  Any ideas?

Comment: I think this is expected behaviour. The variable is of type character, so internal quotes are escaped when displayed in the console. Were you to write the variable to a file, the backslashes would not be present.

Comment: Wrote it to a CSV using write.table(data_temp, "C:/Downloads/test.txt", sep="", row.names = F, col.names=F) and the backslashes remained.